# Python simplifying radicals not going well

Tags: python

So, I have this program returning the square root of 16 to be 4.0; However, it adds a 1.0 afterwards. When I try to input 28 it returns 5.0 1.12 instead of 2(7) (I don't know how to input a square root symbol) and if I input 197 it returns 14.0 1.00510204082 instead of (197). Any help in solving how to make the proper output happen would be appreciated, and here is the code:

```
from math import modf
from math import sqrt
#Establish input
A = int(raw_input("Enter the number under the radical:"))
#Input taken, setup math
B = (A + 1)
C = sqrt(B)
#seperate parts
Fractional, Integral = modf(C)
Fractional1, Integral1 = modf(A / (Integral**2))
def Intg(Integral):
    while Fractional1 == Fractional1:
        if Fractional1 == 0 and (A / (Integral**2)) == 1:
            print (Integral)
            return Integral
        else:
            Integral = (Integral - 1)
if Integral == 1:
    print (A / (Integral**2))
elif not Integral ==1 or (Fractional1 == 0 and (A / (Intergral**2)) == 1):
    print Integral, (A / (Integral**2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick note you spelled Integral wrong on the following line:

`if not Integral ==1 or (Fractional1 == 0 and (A / (Intergral**2)) == 1):`

To put the radical in your output use
`print("The answer is "+ u'\u221a' +str(int(squared)))`

In the instance where you input 16 as the problem, Integral = 4 which is

`elif not Integral ==1 or (Fractional1 == 0 and (A / (Integral**2)) == 1):`

In this condition your code prints out both Integral and A / Integral**2.

`print Integral, (A / (Integral**2))`

A=16; Integral**2=16; 16/16 = 1 , The code prints 4 and 1

When you input 28 your fractional1's will always be zero , because when you divide in python you always get an integer. "28/9 becomes 3.0 instead of 3.1111111..." Instead of using modf you should use the modulus operation 28%9=1 giving you the fractional or remainder you are looking for.

`Integral1 = A / Integral**2
Fractional1 = A%Integral**2`

This does not give you a correct solution though.  You are getting 5 because "sqr(28)=5.29150262.." You want a 7. You can't get that with the square root function. It does give you an approximation though which you could use to better guess what you're answer should be. Iterate through some perfect squares based on 5 and you'll get the answer you are looking for. This is the same thing you do on paper when solving this problem.

`answer = ''
for number in range(2,int(Integral)+1):
    print number
    rem = A%number**2
    if not rem:
        answer = 'The answer is ' + str(number) + u'\u221a' + str(A/number**2)
if not answer:
    print('The answer is '+ u'\u221a' + str(A))
else:

    print answer`

This prints out "2√7" for the answer to the input 28. It also prints out √197 to your input 197. I'm building on this for my own project you can see this on github "https://github.com/Triballian/simprad"